# Downloading folder from GCS to local directory

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I'm trying to download a folder from my Cloud Storage bucket to local directory using the command `gsutil cp -r gs://bucket/my_folder .` . But it is showing OSError : Access is denied. Any idea how to get around this problem?

Comment: Might be permission issues. If you're in Ubuntu, try using `sudo` in front of the command, if you are in Windows, try running your shell session as an Admin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can reproduce this error if I do not have permissions to create `LOCAL_DEST_DIR` on my local machine.

```
$ gsutil cp -r gs://BUCKET_NAME/DIR_IN_BUCKET LOCAL_DEST_DIR
Copying gs://BUCKET_NAME/DIR_IN_BUCKET/FILE...
OSError: Permission denied.
```

Please check you have permissions to create a file/directory in your current working directory.

You can run `touch test-file.text` to verify if you're able to create files in the current directory.

If you're on linux/*nix/mac, usually you will have full permissions to create files and directories in your `$HOME` directory, so you can try running the `gsutil` command in that directory.